# How can i make this line using tailwind css?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

[i don't know how can i make this line using tailwind css.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MvVX.png)

```
 <span className="mt-4 font-medium after: text-slate-500">
```

Answer (score 0):

the erorr is separe the after with the other class

```
<span className="mt-4 font-medium after:text-slate-500">
```